# Select all rows of all user logins, where user had logged in from more than 3 ip address within the past month

Tags: sql-server, query

Our SQL Server UserLogins table has these columns: UserID, DateTime, IpAddress.

How can I select rows of users who have logged in from more than three different ip addresses within a specified time period (e.g., one month), ordered by User ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT` clause inside of a `COUNT()` aggregate function in your `HAVING` clause after applying a `GROUP BY` on the `UserId` like so:

```
WITH CTE_Users_MoreThan3IpAddresses AS
(
    SELECT UserID
    FROM UserLogins
    WHERE [DateTime] >= '01/01/2021' AND [DateTime] < '02/01/2021' -- Sets the date range for logins (1 month example)
    GROUP BY UserID -- Groups all rows of the same UserID up
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IpAddress) > 3 -- Filters out everything except User's with more than 3 unique IP Addresses
)

SELECT U.UserID, U.[DateTime], U.IpAddress
FROM UserLogins AS U
INNER JOIN CTE_Users_MoreThan3IpAddresses AS C
    ON U.UserID = C.UserID
ORDER BY U.UserID
```

Note you should be careful what names you use for your columns. `DateTime` is a reserved keyword in the SQL language to represent a data type, which is why I put the square brackets around it in this example (which tells SQL to actually treat it as a column name).

Comment: @Lennart Oh shoot you're right Lol. Sorry I literally just woke up so the gears are still turning, I'll fix now.

Comment: @Lennart Good catch, thanks again!

Comment: Your SQL will include data for the first of Feb!

Comment: @Verace Only at midnight. ;) Fixed, but was probably immaterial to OPs question anyway. :)

Answer (score 4):

We can actually do this in one scan of the table, by using window functions. Unfortunately, we cannot use `COUNT(DISTINCT...` as a window aggregate, so we must hack it with `DENSE_RANK` and `MAX`

```sql
SELECT UserID, [DateTime], IpAddress
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, [DateTime], IpAddress,
        distinctIps = MAX(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID)
    FROM (
        SELECT UserID, [DateTime], IpAddress,
            rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY IpAddress)
            -- row-number distinct ip addresses
        FROM UserLogins
        WHERE [DateTime] >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
    ) ul
) ul
WHERE distinctIps > 3;
```

Comment: Very nice! I was actually going to add a similar query as an additional answer to mine, but when I recalled you can't use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` as a **window function** unfortunately, I gave up and was satisfied enough with my existing answer. But this was good thinking outside the box. :)